# how can I find, which are the systems connected to my router?

Tags: router, authentication, wireless-networking, routing

I have Belkin wireless G router (For my home network) and I want to know, is there anyway to find out which are the systems currently accessing that router and is it possible to disconnect one of the system from that network?

Comment: Give us more information such as the model of your router so we can tell you what options you have, most routers you can limit the usage by mac, password authentication using radius and other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest nmap (zenmap[spelling?] for windows) for network probing as well, its safe as long as you only run it on your local network, and with the right options it can give you a lot of info on the hosts on your network.   Its free, and open-source, and used in a lot of pro and home network testing.

as for kicking systems, you will have to see if your router supports mac address filters, some consumer routers do out of the box, some might take an update, or an install of a 3rd party OS (ddwrt/openwrt) to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Your router will have to have the functionality to detect things connected to it, this is the easiest way.  Most Linksys and D-Link routers will tell you both who is connected via Ethernet, and who is connected via wireless Ethernet.  You should look at your router';s control panel login page first.

Failing that, get a program that will do a "network probe" such as Cisco NetMagic, network magic, or some other network analysis program.  This should "ping" and "probe" every device on your network, and bring back all relevant information it can find.

You can disconnect a user by blocking their MAC address from your router, again, this is per make and per model.  Please tell us this information.

Comment: I am using Belkin wireless G router